# how to pop up a new form window withing the opened window on clicking a new add item button in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

Hello I am using SP 2013 online and on the my main page, I have a button "Add new item" Like this [image]

When I click it, it open a new form and replace the current window which I don't want. So right now it behaves this way:[image]

What I want is: that when I click on the button it pop up the new form window above the opened window. This pic shows the desired behavior.[image]

How can I achieve this in SharePoint? I am a new user of SharePoint. Please help me to figure it out.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option in custom lists to launch forms as a pop up or dialog box as you've displayed.

To get this to happen:

You can always try > List Settings > Advanced Settings > Launch forms in a dialog? Yes

Just be aware that if a user has pop up blockers set on their browser it may open up in the window (your first screen shot) or not at all.

See if that helps.